# XOR NN not learnable with 2 hidden nodes and sigmoid activation?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, xor, activation-function

I felt like my backpropagation intuition wasn't crystal clear, so I wrote a neural network class to train/predict on XOR. It has 2 inputs, 1 output, a variable number of hidden nodes, and bias nodes for the hidden and output layer.

What I noticed is that when I change the number of hidden nodes from 3 to 2, no matter what sizes I use for epochs/lr, it doesn't seem to be able to learn the problem with a sigmoid activation function. However, if I change the activation function to tanh, it will learn with only 2 hidden nodes.

I'm thinking there could be three causes:

1. Can't learn XOR with single hidden layer and only 2 nodes (This seems unlikely because I've seen many graphics depicting this network)
2. Can't learn XOR with combination of sigmoid activation function and single hidden layer with only two nodes
3. I have an error in my code or haven't considered something else

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes,
                 lr, activation='sigmoid'):
        self.epoch_count = 0
        self.activation = activation
        self.sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1+np.exp(-x))
        if activation == 'tanh': self.nonlinearity = lambda x: np.tanh(x)
        elif activation == 'relu': self.nonlinearity = lambda x: x * (x > 0)
        else: self.nonlinearity = self.sigmoid
        self.inodes = input_nodes
        self.hnodes = hidden_nodes
        self.onodes = output_nodes
        self.wih = np.random.normal(0.0, self.xavier_he_init_std(self.inodes,self.hnodes), (self.hnodes, self.inodes))
        self.who = np.random.normal(0.0, self.xavier_he_init_std(self.inodes,self.hnodes), (self.onodes, self.hnodes))
        self.bo = np.zeros((self.onodes,1))
        self.bh = np.zeros((self.hnodes,1))
        self.lr = lr

    def xavier_he_init_std(self,n_in,n_out):
        if self.activation == 'tanh':
            return np.sqrt(4)*np.sqrt(2/(n_in+n_out))
        elif self.activation == 'relu':
            return np.sqrt(2)*np.sqrt(2/(n_in+n_out))
        else: # sigmoid
            return np.sqrt(2/(n_in+n_out))

    def predict(self,X):
        self.forward(X)
        bin_thresh = 0.5
        probs = self.final_outputs.T
        class_predictions = [1 if i > bin_thresh else 0 for i in probs]
        return class_predictions

    def fit(self, X, y, verbose=True):
        self.forward(X)
        self.backward(y)
        self.epoch_count += 1
        if verbose and (self.epoch_count%100==0):
            print("epoch %4d mse loss:" % self.epoch_count, self.mse_loss)

    def forward(self, X, output=False):
        self.X = np.array(X).T
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, self.X) + self.bh # broadcast biases
        self.hidden_outputs = self.nonlinearity(hidden_inputs)
        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, self.hidden_outputs) + self.bo
        self.final_outputs = self.sigmoid(final_inputs)
        if output: return self.final_outputs

    def backward(self, y):
        y = np.array(y).T
        self.mse_loss = np.square((y-self.final_outputs)).mean()

        # CHAIN RULE FOR WEIGHT UPDATES
        # Hidden-Output layer weights update
        # =================================================================
        # Need to calculate the partial derivative of the loss with respect
        # to each weight in the layer Who
        # partial derivative of the error with respect to the output ∂E/∂O:
        # (1/n)*(targets-predictions)^2 -> (2/n)*(target-actual)*-1 -> (-2/n)*sum(target-actual)
        dEdO_Who = -2*(y-self.final_outputs)
        # partial derivative of the output with respect to the net input ∂O/∂X:
        # 1 / (1 + e^(-N)) -> sigmoid(N)*(1-sigmoid(N)) -> O*(1-O)
        dOdN_Who = self.final_outputs * (1-self.final_outputs)
        # partial derivative of the net inputs with respect to the weights ∂N/∂W:
        # Net_ho = W1*X1+W2+X2... -> X1,X2,...
        dNdW_Who = self.hidden_outputs
        # multiplying each part of the chain rule together:
        dEdW_Who = np.dot((dEdO_Who * dOdN_Who),  dNdW_Who.T) # dot b.c. of batch inputs
        # update the weights by multiplying by the learning rate
        nabla_Who = self.lr * dEdW_Who
        nabla_bo = self.lr * np.dot((dEdO_Who * dOdN_Who), np.expand_dims(np.ones(y.shape),axis=1))

        # Input-Hidden layer weights update: backpropagating errors
        # =================================================================
        # Need to calculate the partial derivative of the loss with respect
        # to each weight in the layer wih
        # similar but slightly different process because the output of each hidden
        # layer neuron contributes to the output/error of multiple output neurons
        # For Example, ∂E/∂Wih_1 = sum_over_outputs(∂E/∂out_o ∂out_o/∂net_o . . .
        # * ∂net_o/∂out_h) * ∂out_h/∂net_h * ∂net_h/∂wih_1
        # This equals sum(δ_o * Who) * out_h * (1 - out_h) * i_1
        # where δ_o = ∂E/∂net = ∂E/∂out * ∂out/∂net
        # errors from hidden layer split output error proportionally by weight contributions
        dEdO_Wih = np.dot(self.who.T, dEdO_Who) # first three p.d. terms
        dOdN_Wih = self.hidden_outputs * (1-self.hidden_outputs)
        dNdW_Wih = self.X # inputs
        dEdW_Wih = np.dot((dEdO_Wih * dOdN_Wih), dNdW_Wih.T)
        nabla_Wih = self.lr * dEdW_Wih
        nabla_bh = self.lr * np.dot((dEdO_Wih * dOdN_Wih), np.expand_dims(np.ones(y.shape),axis=1))

        # update the weights and biases
        self.who -= nabla_Who
        self.wih -= nabla_Wih
        self.bo -= nabla_bo
        self.bh -= nabla_bh

def main():

    X_train = [
        (0, 0),
        (0, 1),
        (1, 0),
        (1, 1)
    ]
    y_train = [0,1,1,0]

    sz = lambda l: 1 if (isinstance(l[0], int) or isinstance(l[0], float)) else len(l[0])
    input_nodes = sz(X_train)
    output_nodes = sz(y_train)

    hidden_nodes = 2
    epochs = 500
    lr=0.1

    nn = NeuralNetwork(input_nodes,hidden_nodes,output_nodes,lr,activation='tanh')

    # train
    for _ in range(epochs):
        nn.fit(X_train, y_train,verbose=True)
    # predict
    print(nn.predict(X_train))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Would someone please explain what's going wrong with 2 hidden nodes + sigmoid?

Comment: It's been a while. I also have the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738146/xor-neural-network-does-not-learn

Comment: Look at this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/creating-neural-net-for-xor-function

Comment: In particular, look at this article: http://yen.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/techreps/pdf/TR148.pdf